# Compile time function from enum?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm using XMacro COMPS to define enums and some other metadata like name, index, flag=(1<<index), etc at compilation time.

Here's an example how I'm using it to generate the index:

```
template <unsigned ROUTINE>
constexpr int C_Index()
{
    switch (ROUTINE)
    {
    #define MX(a,b) case a: return b; break;
        COMPS
    #undef MX
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not using C++20, so consteval is out of option but this construction that I have certainly looks overly cumbersome. Is there a better way to achieve the same effect in C++17?

Comment: Not a portable one. Reflection (when we get it) is going to be more comprehensive instead of singling out enums.

Comment: @chris Thanks! I've seen the topic around, I'll give it a look!

Comment: When you say XMacro I guess you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro

Comment: Correct @JohnZwinck.